# FlowDocumentScrollViewer vs FlowDocumentPageViewer

Tags: wpf, performance, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have 2 possible ways to display my FlowDocument:

**FlowDocumentScrollViewer**

Upside:

- This just presents me the data, with no attention to pages, so the user simply scrolls through everything. On printing I can add a header and a footer and the pages are decided there.

- When I resize my window, the content stays correctly at 100% zoom, as I want it to be.

Downside:

- With a lot of data it just crashes, it seems to render all controls at once, or something.

**FlowDocumentPageViewer**

Upside:

- With a lot of data it's still fast.

Downside:

- It decides pages for me, which are irrelevant.

- When I resize my window, the content zooms out to fit the window. Which makes the content unreadable very quickly. Possible fix to this is surrounding the control with a ScrollViewer, which works. But when you scroll down to view bottom page content, at the end it goes to the next page, and if you then scroll up too far it goes to previous page, very annoying.

---

What I eventually want is the FlowDocumentScrollViewer, but then with fast loading time.

Anyone with any ideas/tips on this matter? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use a FlowDocumentReader then the user can can go scroll or page at run time.  This will not solve stability problems.   I display some documents with 200,000 characters and it is stable for me.  It load via Dispatcher so may want to look there.

Comment: But don't you find it annoying that it zooms to fit the window? I currently use the FlowDocumentPageViewer, with a stripped Template and an external navigation bar. Surrounded by a ScrollViewer to disable the zooming.

Comment: Zoom to fit the Window is the behavior I want and it does not make the content unreadable unless I make it real small but if I want to view a document I don't make it real small.